# static and final in java

Tags: java, static, final

I was reading about enumeration examples in Java from [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/enums.html) page.

In the first example, the only part I did not understand was the use of the `static` keyword in this part of the code:

```
private static final List<Card> protoDeck = new ArrayList<Card>();

// Initialize prototype deck
static {
    for (Suit suit : Suit.values())
        for (Rank rank : Rank.values())
            protoDeck.add(new Card(rank, suit));
}

public static ArrayList<Card> newDeck() {
    return new ArrayList<Card>(protoDeck); // Return copy of prototype deck
}
```

Why is the protoDeck declared `static` and `final`? Following that, a static loop is used to initialize the protoDeck. I know about static variables that they retain their values between instances of objects. But this is a singleton class (private constructor), so it cannot be instantiated.

So what is the benefit of doing it as above? what would be the implications if proteDeck is not `static` and `final` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Technically, this is *not* a singleton class. (A singleton has *one* instance, this one has *none*!)

It is a **factory method** for an `ArrayList<Card>`, and the method `newDeck` works the same way as a constructor would for a class "CardArrayList". It's not a Java constructor but a factory method, but other than that it serves the same purpose: creating new card decks.

Using a class `CardArrayList` and subtyping `ArrayList` would obviously be an alternative. Try this as an exercise: write such as class so that it serves the same purpose. Try to use a constant (`static final`) for keeping the initial set of objects. You'll notice that there is little difference between these two, except that this approach clearly says that there is no added functionality, but the result is "nothing but an `ArrayList<Card>` containing a full deck". Subclassing might imply that there is extra functionality, such as ensuring the deck is not messed with.

The `static final` variable contains the prototype that serves as template for new objects.

Comment: Thanks. Sorry it is not a singleton. I will try to do the alternative you have suggested. That way I can understand it better!

Answer (score 1):

The static { .... } portion of your code will be executed where your class is loaded by the Java Virtual Machine.

In your code segment, it's used to initialize the protoDeck ArrayList.

This is not following the Singleton pattern, since there's no evidence in your code that shows that the class is instantiated only one time.

Comment: technically, it's not when the class is loaded, but when initialized (ie, you access a field or method which is declared directly in that class), but close enough :)

Answer (score 1):

In the class initialization (the code in the `static` brackets) the program generates all the cards of the deck and stores it in `protoDeck`.

When `newDeck` is called, a shallow copy of the deck is returned. It means that all the cards object in the game are the same object (there is only one "Ace of Spades" card). They are managed in several different decks, though.

IMHO it is a little too complicated for this example, it would have more sense if instead of `Cards` where other kind of classes (one where initialization would be costly/expensive in RAM, or other where they were representing system resources -database connections or similar-).

Answer (score 0):

If it isn't static, the code won't compile because the newDeck method is static,  And newDeck is static because you don't get a different deck for different cards.

Making it not final wouldn't do anything different.  It's final in that you can't assign a different array.  But you can still add to it, so it isn't immutable.  So it is a common clue, but not a change in behavior.

Comment: Well, "it has to be `static` because it won't compile otherwise" is a pretty useless explanation of *why* it was designed this way...

Comment: True.  I've elaborated on that.

Answer (score 0):

The `final` keyword in Java enables all kinds of compile-time magic. For instance, when the compiler **knows** that a variable will never be reassigned, it can perform  "[memoization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memoization)" optimizations.

This alone is a good reason to `final`-ize local variables, parameters, and class members by default -- unless you really have to be able to reassign them, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If `protoDeck` was not `static` there would be one for each `Card` and that would not be a good thing.

Obviously, you can only construct a `static` variable with `static` code.

`final` just means the `protoDeck` will never be replaced (although it can be changed internally).